# Can Flyway accomodate different SQL dialects in the same migration script?

Tags: database, flyway

in my Company we manage a SaaS infrastructure that uses PostgreSQL as DB solution. However, some clients wants us to perform an on-premise deployment, in which they provide MySQL instead.

This of course entails identifying and isolate PG-specific datatypes and functions, find a corresponding MySQL equivalent, and make them run properly.

If we were using Liquibase, that would be easy, since it would require me to write `databaseChangeLog`(s) with a precondition like this:

```
<preConditions onFail="HALT">
    <dbms type="mysql"/>
</preConditions>
```

and include as many as I want **within the same `databaseChangeLog`**

With Flyway however, [it seems like the only possible way is to define different folders, under which place the SQL files for a particular RDBMS](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/faq#db-specific-sql).

This seems quite overkill and error-prone to me, so I would like to know: **does Flyway have some specific syntax that I missed, which allows me to write different SQL-dialect-specific queries within the same `.sql` file?** I.E. I would hypothetically expect something like this :

```
--; if(mysql)
CREATE TABLE test (start_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);
--; endif

--; if(postgresql)
CREATE TABLE test (start_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL);
--; endif

...
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature of flyway. SQL scripts in flyway are meant to be purely valid SQL (with some exceptions for variable injection).

However, you may be able to look at [Java](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/tutorials/java) migrations to do conditional execution but you would not be able to do that with your existing SQL scripts.

Comment: not sure how that would work for my specific scenario.. i don't need to migrate/update data from one RDBMS to another, but rather, be able to support either one type or an other, depending on the deployment type (in-house vs on-premise). Probably the only way is to provide specific folders for the specific RDBMS flavor, and configure which one to use at deploy time.

Answer (score 0):

Flyway doesn't support conditional blocks within migration files but it is possible for SQL dialects to use the same migration scripts.

I've used flyway placeholders to do this, rather than conditional blocks. I've got a demonstration of the technique [here](https://github.com/Phil-Factor/PubsAndFlyway/tree/main/PubsAgnostic), using PowerShell as the glue. Yours sounds an interesting application, I have the same requirement for an application that can be installed in various environments that use a different brand of RDBMS, and I can see the value of  block structures. The reason that I used placeholders was that the difference between SQL dialects us usually fairly trivial. Maybe a combination of techniques would be a winner.

I would guess that you can use SQL conditional blocks together with placeholders. You would just then  need a placeholder with the name of your rdbms, taken from the flyway.conf jdbc connection-string.

Comment: Indeed, the changes were quite contained so in the end we opted for the solution using different folders: one for the common sql scripts, one for mysql, and one for postgresql. A simple, one liner addition to the configuration file would then instruct Flyway from which specific sql dialect to read from. This way client's devops team have less to worry about. Interesting solutions btw, good to know!